# I want to resize text along with the image to fit any screen

Tags: html, css

Right now, the size of the image is responsive but the text is all over the place. I could use @Media query but how many since every resize seems to split text. Please let me know how to achieve an image and text that respond to multiple screen sizes.

Here's HTML:

```
    <div class="jus-style"></div>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <h1 class="main-heading text-center text-uppercase">Christopher Eric Hitchens</h1>
        <div class="row">
              <div class="overlay">
                   <img class="main-image img-responsive" src="hitchens1.jpg" alt="chris hitchens pic taken from the web. i don't own it">

               <q class="over-image">Owners of dogs will have noticed that, if you provide them with food and water and shelter and affection, they will think you are God. Whereas owners of cats are compelled to realize that, if you provide them with food and water and affection, they draw the conclusion that they are God.</q>

                 <p class="whosaidit"><cite><a href="https://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/quotes/c/christophe472423.html" rel="quotes by Chris Hitchens from Brainy Quote website" target="_blank">Brainy Quote</a></cite><small style="font-style: italic;"> - Christopher Hitchens</small></p>
              </div>
        </div>

Here's CSS:
.over-image {
position: absolute;
top: 1em;
right: 1em;
width: 50%;
margin-right: 3em;
padding-right: 10%;
padding-left: 20%;
padding-top: 200px;
color: white;
letter-spacing: 2px;
font-style: italic;
text-align: ;
}

.whosaidit {
position: absolute;
top: 29.7em;
right: 10em;
color: white;

}

a:hover {
color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set your image as a background image of an element in this case the overlay class is set to hold a background image. I structure the content on the inside with flexbox properties, but you can accommodate it to your needs. The content will resize all together. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qsvjo1tf/1/)

```css
.overlay{
  background-image: url("https://placehold.it/500x400");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  height: 400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

a:hover {
color: green;
}
```

```html
    <div class="jus-style"></div>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <h1 class="main-heading text-center text-uppercase">Christopher Eric Hitchens</h1>
        <div class="row">
              <div class="overlay">
               <p class="over-image">Owners of dogs will have noticed that, if you provide them with food and water and shelter and affection, they will think you are God. Whereas owners of cats are compelled to realize that, if you provide them with food and water and affection, they draw the conclusion that they are God.</p>

                 <p class="whosaidit"><cite><a href="https://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/quotes/c/christophe472423.html" rel="quotes by Chris Hitchens from Brainy Quote website" target="_blank">Brainy Quote</a></cite><small style="font-style: italic;"> - Christopher Hitchens</small></p>
              </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: works for the text, thanks. but the image isn't resizing to viewport now.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look here at **[Viewport Sized Typography](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/)**

> CSS3 has some new values for sizing things relative to the current
>   viewport size: vw, vh, and vmin. It is relevant to bring up now,
>   because it's shipping in Chrome 20 (canary at the time of this
>   writing). And not behind a flag, it just works. Production usage isn't
>   quite there, but it will be soon enough.

Here are browser support [information](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)

*How to use them ?*

**Examples:**

```
h1 {
  font-size: 5.9vw;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 3.0vh;
}
p {
  font-size: 2vmin;
}
```

Here is a [demo website](https://css-tricks.com/examples/ViewportTypography/) using this.

**DEMO GIF**

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Got it. Here's what I did.

I added a section under  and styled that. Then media queries to match the least view port.

```css
.overlay {
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 600px;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 0;
  background: url("hitchens1.jpg") no-repeat 50% 50%;
  background-size: cover;
}

.quotation {
  max-width: 30%;
  margin-left: 60%;
  text-align: left;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 8em;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: justify;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .quotation {
    padding-bottom: 50%;
  }
  .overlay {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: url("hitchens1.jpg") no-repeat 30% 30%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay">

  <section class="quotation">

    <q>Owners of dogs will have noticed that, if you provide them with food and water and shelter and affection, they will think you are God. Whereas owners of cats are compelled to realize that, if you provide them with food and water and affection, they draw the conclusion that they are God.</q>

    <p class="whosaidit"><cite><a href="https://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/quotes/c/christophe472423.html" rel="quotes by Chris Hitchens from Brainy Quote website" target="_blank">Brainy Quote</a></cite><small style="font-style: italic;"> - Christopher Hitchens</small></p>
  </section>
</div>
```